# Не сохраняет значение переменной при выходе из ф-ии C#

Tags: c#, функции, память, структуры

Добрый вечер. Столкнулся с проблемой: одна ф-ия сохраняет значение переменной mas.values(int[,]), что можно использовать в других ф-ях, а другая ф-ия не сохраняет значение переменной mas.average(float). Ф-ии объявлены одинаково. В чём проблема?

весь код: [тык](https://pastebin.com/NcxPxZZk)

p.s. только вчера начал изучение C#

это рабочая ф-ия

```
static public void Sort(ARRAY mas) //сортировка
        {
            int temp;       //"буферная" переменная
            for (int m = 0; m < mas.size1 * mas.size2; m++)
                for (int k = 0; k < mas.size1; k++)
                    for (int l = 0; l < mas.size2 - 1; l++)
                    {
                        if (mas.values[k, l] > mas.values[k, l + 1])
                        {
                            temp = mas.values[k, l];
                            mas.values[k, l] = mas.values[k, l + 1];
                            mas.values[k, l + 1] = temp;
                        }
                    }
        }
```

а это не хочет сохранять значение mas.average

```
 static public void Arg(ARRAY mas)        // среднее значение
        {
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.size1; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < mas.size2; j++)
                    sum += mas.values[i, j];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("sum =" + sum);
            mas.average = sum / mas.size1 * mas.size2;
            Console.WriteLine(mas.average + "<-arg");
        }
```

Comment: Что значит не сохраняет?

Comment: при использовании переменных в других ф-ях mas.value имеет прежнее значение, которое получила в ф-ии выше, а переменная mas.average равна 1(вначале задаётся конструктором) после выхода из ф-ии ниже.

Comment: Загрузи на какой-нибудь сайт типа pastebin свой код целиком.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/NcxPxZZk

Comment: Структуры в функции передаются по значению, а не по ссылке, поэтому у вас переменные и не изменяются. Только в первом случае по значению копируется ссылка на массив, поэтому работает, а во втором переменная average не ссылочная.

Comment: @Андрей Товарищ Alex Krass прав. И в вашем случае проще `struct ARRAY` поменять на `class ARRAY`, тогда программа заработает. Или можно во все функции передавать `mas` по ссылке, то есть вместо `(ARRAY mas)` в функциях писать `(ref ARRAY mas)`.

Comment: [Еще материал по этой теме](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/)
При передаче в качестве параметра у которого тип "struct", будет передана его копия полная, но т.к. одно из его полей массив(ссылочный тип), то он останется прежним.

Comment: @AK, ничего не понял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за советы, задачу удалось решить посредством передачи `mas` по ссылке, то есть :

**Было**

```
 static public void Arg(ARRAY mas)  
  Arg(mas);
```

**Стало**

```
 static public void Arg(ref ARRAY mas)  
  Arg(ref mas);
```